# Problems with audio-out on a headset

Tags: sound

I have to use teams a lot and have had longstanding problems on my ubuntu desktop, now v21.04.

After many problems I finally got it working perfectly for several months after I connected my headphones through a bose USB link instead of a generic bluetooth dongle.

Until I did a recorded job interview thing through an online platform in firefox, the microphone didn't initially work then firefox automatically installed some codecs or something (I had never used a microphone within firefox before so it could be unrelated to the specific webapp), and sound has not worked through my headset since.

Now I can't get sound through my headset (it's not a problem with the headset or the link, they both work perfectly an a windows computer). My desktop thinks my headphones are connected, pavucontrol even shows the bar moving of the sound allegedly coming out of them and the microphone works perfectly so they are definitely connected, there's just no audio out.

I've tried

- various troubleshooting steps with system settings from online guides
- removing pulseaudio (desktop stops recognising the bose link at all)
- uninstalling firefox (hoping it might remove whatever was installed)
- factory resetting both headset and usb link
- looking through logs to see if any packages were installed on the date (no)

How do I find out what was installed when firefox wanted the mic? Has anyone encountered any similar problems before?

Thank you.

Edit: I have discovered that playing with levels in alsamixer does result in some poor quality mono sound output with some high pitched interference (previously I had and on other computers I have high quality stereo). This is in both ears, but is the "left" side only (based on the "front left", "front right" test in settings, previously both these were silent).

Edit again: with further playing I've got poor quality sound with microphone, good quality without, similar to a HSP headset. However there's no reason it needs to be as a HSP, my understanding is the Bose USB link presents itself to the computer as a separate sound card rather than a bluetooth headset and I have always been able to have good quality audio and microphone working at the same time, so there's no reason it needs to use HSP. I have tried the advice on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205749/how-permanently-remove-or-disable-hsp-hfp-bluetooth-profile) and its links to disable HSP but this doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)

Comment: No, unfortunately not.