# Headset Configuration Automatically Changes From High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) to Headset Head Unit(HSP/HFB)

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I just installed ubuntu 20.04 and was using Bluetooth headset with it. The sound at first was all right but whenever I change the microphone (input) device to headset the output configuration changes to `Headset Head Unit(HSP/HFB)`. It actually doesn't show the changes but the sound quality is clearly noticeable. And when I try to change the output configuration back to `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)`, the input device automatically changes to `Headset Microphone - Built-in Audio`.

So, is there a way I can get both output configuration to `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)` and input device to `Headset`?

Any Help Would be Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably the same issue as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085480/bluetooth-headphones-switches-from-a2dp-sink-to-hsp-hfp-when-starting-voip-a).

To summarize:

Basically you need to change this line in the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa:`

```
### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
.endif
```

to

```
### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
load-module module-bluetooth-policy auto_switch=false
.endif
```